# Let device act as printer

Tags: android, printing

I am trying to connect my Android Tablet to a hospital machine.
This machine has the ability to print to several printers like a "Canon IP2600".
But when I connect my Tablet to the machine and try to print from the machine to the tablet, the machine says: USB Printer not found. (of course).

Now my question is, how can I make the machine think there is a printer connected instead of an android tablet?

My theory is: when connecting the tablet to the machine, the tablet usb device descriptor is sent to the machine and this device descriptor doesn't resemble one of a "Canon IP2600".

Am I thinking in the right direction? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: How are you connecting the 2 devices?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK tablets aren't designed to be "printed" to.

I'm not saying what you want to do is impossible, but I'm not sure if it's realistic. You're going to be looking at building a lot of custom software. In order to "print" to a usb device, you're going to need to write drivers for you OS (I'm assuming windows) that will allow the computer to see that cable connection as a printer. Even after you've done that, you need to write some more drivers and software to allow the tablet to understand when it's been connected to a computer and accept incoming prints.

I'm not sure how flexible your requirements are, but a more realistic option might be to use Google Drive (formerly Google Docs). You could print on the computer to a PDF file (using something like PrimoPDF) and save it directly in the Google Drive folder. With sync setup, the file would be available on your tablet using the Google Drive App within seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the information but the hospital machine runs a custom OS. This OS already has drivers for printing to "Canon IP2600". I assume this means I won't need to write a custom driver?

Comment: Also, unfortunately there is very little flexibility. I have been able to get a hospital machine to print to my Android Tablet using TCP/IP and retrieving PCL5 code on the tablet, but USB printing is more important.

Comment: In the end I found (partly) was I was looking for:
On the galaxy tab 2 10.1 at least there is a map (if you have root privileges) "/sys/class/android_usb/android_usb/android0" ... which contains some of the files which contain how the android device ID's itself when connected as ... e.g. "idVendor". You can change the value and I made it act like it's a printer. Now this isn't 100% what I want yet but it's a step in the right direction. (just in case someone was wondering)